# How to track down the type of uncaught exception?

Tags: exception, haskell

Coming from JVM languages which output a mammoth stack-trace whenever an exception is uncaught, I feel frustrated when I see something like `connect: does not exist (Connection refused)` and nothing else in the output of my program and then it closes. I understand that some exception got raised and not caught. I even expected an exception to occur, since I tried to connect to an offline server. So all I need is just a way to handle this exception, but what I don't understand is how I am supposed to find out what type of that exception is to do that.

What I usually did to this day was just google for the specific message and dig thru all the mail-list archives or source files in search for information, but that can't be the right approach. So, my question is as in the title:

**How to track down the type of uncaught exception?**

Comment: Normally, one should print the type of the exception. But how would that help you in this case? The message is quite clear, isn't it?

Comment: I need to write a `catch` against some specific type of exception. This message has no useful info in that regard.

Comment: Your question implies that you've searched the code for the string `connect: does not exist (Connection refused)` and didn't find it. I get the impression that the message in question is coming from a lower layer (e.g. a socks5 proxy), and all the Haskell code is doing is creating an exception and setting the message to whatever has been passed to it. If you can find where that's happening, then maybe you can determine the type of the exception.

Comment: @mhwombat In this particular case I already know the type of exception, it is `IOError` of type `NoSuchThing` and it is testable against with standard `isDoesNotExistError` function.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`typeOf`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Data-Typeable.html#v%3atypeOf) to print the type of the exception:

```
import Data.Typeable
import Control.Exception
import System.IO.Error

blackbox1 :: IO ()
blackbox1 = throw $ mkIOError doesNotExistErrorType "blackbox1" Nothing (Just "evil")

blackbox2 :: IO ()
blackbox2 = throw DivideByZero

traceExceptionName :: IO () -> IO ()
traceExceptionName act = act `catch` \(SomeException e) -> do
  let rep = typeOf e
      tyCon = typeRepTyCon rep
  putStrLn $ "## Exception: Type " ++ show rep ++ " from module " ++ tyConModule tyCon ++ " from package " ++ tyConPackage tyCon
--  throw e -- Rethrow exception.

main :: IO ()
main = do
  traceExceptionName blackbox1
  traceExceptionName blackbox2
```

---

Example output

```
$ runhaskell ./main.hs            
## Exception: Type IOException from module GHC.IO.Exception from package base
## Exception: Type ArithException from module GHC.Exception from package base
```

Comment: Is it possible to use `TypeRep` to get some more information about the package or module that defined the particular exceptions?

Comment: @J.Abrahamson yes, I updated my answer to include that information.

Answer (score 4):

This is genuinely one of the very worst parts of Haskell—it's very hard to get stack traces out of it.

The most direct way is to compile the program for profiling then call it with the RTS option

```
myprog +RTS -xc -RTS
```

which will dump a stack trace, though I've heard it's a little buggy and may not work well. This is the example from the documentation

```
*** Exception raised (reporting due to +RTS -xc), stack trace:
  GHC.List.CAF
  --> evaluated by: Main.polynomial.table_search,
  called from Main.polynomial.theta_index,
  called from Main.polynomial,
  called from Main.zonal_pressure,
  called from Main.make_pressure.p,
  called from Main.make_pressure,
  called from Main.compute_initial_state.p,
  called from Main.compute_initial_state,
  called from Main.CAF
```

I've gone as far as grepping the source for particular error strings, though, when `-xc` didn't provide enough extra information.

If you've got an uncatchable exception rising up through a particular library and you'd like to handle it in a more pure way, you may like to use the functions in the `spoon` package to convert it to a pure `Maybe` result. From there you can re-raise it via your own exceptions. That may make the error easier to handle as well.

Comment: There is also a new function Debug.Trace.traceStack which is like Debug.Trace.trace but also prints a call stack trace if one is available.

Comment: Tried it. While this does print out where the exception got raised, it doesn't print it's type.

Comment: @DonStewart I didn't know that was there—exciting!

Answer (score 4):

If all you need is the type, why not use [typeOf](http://haddocks.fpcomplete.com/fp/7.4.2/20130922-179/base/Data-Typeable-Internal.html#v%3atypeOf)? All exceptions must be instances of `Typeable`.

Answer (score 1):

I like J. Abrahamson's answer, but if that fails or you want an alternative... I temporarily write a handler that catches "all" exceptions, only to print out the name of the exception. Once I have that, I modify the exception handler to deal with only the exception(s) I can handle.

But read the [warning about "Catching all exceptions"](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Control-Exception.html#v%3acatch)

---

EDIT: Here's some sample code:

```
catch XXXXXXX
  (\e -> do
     let err = show (e :: SomeException)
     hPutStr stderr ("Warning: " ++ err)
     return ())
```

Comment: Nifty! And seems much simpler. How exactly does your handler look like?

Comment: It prints out the same thing in my case. I.e.: `connect: does not exist (Connection refused)`. I suspect it to behave the same way in other cases too, since it's using the `Show` instance.